# How to use Python Requests to submit radio button form?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to learn about web interaction, specifically using Requests.

To that end, I'm interested in using Python with Requests to download a list of car parts from OReillyAuto.com But I'm running into a hiccup.

When I browse to [this url](http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/c/search/Brake+Pads+&+Shoes/C0068/C0009.oap?model=G6&vi=1432754&year=2006&make=Pontiac), it should show me a list of brake pads and shoes for the type of car I've specified. However, it pops up a set of radio buttons asking if I want to view parts for the left side, right side, or all parts.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make that selection and get the HTML that I can see in the Chrome dev tools, which contains a list of brand-names, prices, etc.

I've tried a number of things, but this is what I have now:

```
#import HTTP libraries
import requests
#import HTML parsing libraries
import bs4

url = 'http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/c/search/Brake+Pads+&+Shoes/C0068/C0009.oap?model=G6&vi=1432754&year=2006&make=Pontiac'

answerURL = 'http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/ConditionSelectServlet?answer=-1'

print("Making request")
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'referer': url})
r = session.get(answerURL)
print(r.status_code)

oreillyList = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

print("Writing response...")
logfile = 'C:/Users/mhurley/Portable_Python/notebooks/' + output + '.log' 
with open(logfile, 'w') as file:
    file.write(oreillyList.prettify())
print("...done writing "+logfile)
```

I expect the log file that I write out to have about 5200 lines in it, as I do when I "View Page Source." However, I'm only getting about 3000 lines, and it looks like there are no parts in that list.

Maybe I really am getting what I think I am, but I'm not interpreting it correctly. Any tips for how to get past this dialog request?

**EDIT:** I suspect this is the HTML relevant to my purposes:

```
<div id="forcedVehicleQuestions" class="forcedUserInput" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 40px; z-index: 6000; margin-left: -199px; margin-top: 0px;">
        <div class="forcedContents clearfix">
            <a class="btn-remove" onclick="closeForced('Search','question');">
                <svg><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#shape-remove"></use></svg>
            </a>
            <form name="forcedQuestionsForm" id="forcedQuestionsForm">
                <h2 class="sans">
                    More Product Info Required
                </h2>
                <p id="questionText" class="questionText">
                    Brake Pads - Position
                </p>
                <div id="forceQuestionsRadio">

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="questionRadio checkbox-radio" id="questionRadio" for="Front">
                                <input type="radio" id="Front" name="answer" value="10219">
                                Front
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="questionRadio checkbox-radio" id="questionRadio" for="Rear">
                                <input type="radio" id="Rear" name="answer" value="10290">
                                Rear
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="questionRadio checkbox-radio" id="questionRadio" for="Show all">
                                <input type="radio" id="Show all" checked="" name="answer" value="-1">
                                Show all
                            </label>
                        </div>

                </div>

                <input id="questionSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-green btn-shadow" value="Continue" onclick="setQuestionAnswer('Brake Pads - Position',document.forms['forcedQuestionsForm'].elements['answer'],'Show all');">

                <div id="forcedVehicleQuestionsLoading" class="loading load-sm">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm having a hard time understanding how to interact with this `<form>` element. How can I make the "onclick=" happen so that the form gets submitted?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use a combination of [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) + BeautifulSoup.

First, you'll use selenium to open the webpage in a browser, select the right radio button then submit the form.

After this, use BeautifulSoup to parse the page for the brakes.

Comment: Thanks! I've heard a lot about Selenium, I guess I'll have to look into it. Can you elaborate a bit on why Requests can't interact with the `<form>` tag that OReilly's is using for those radio buttons?

Comment: Requests is unable to interact with the form because it's submitted through an AJAX request. The client requires Javascript support to browse the page.